# How to prevent sent strings from being capitalized by the + prefix

Tags: autohotkey, prefix

so I'm making a script which at some point sends out a phrase with a + in front of it (macro to be used in a case sensitive command console) but it just becomes capital letter.

Basically, if I want to send "+a", I'd write

```
send +a
```

but that just returns "A". How can I get the actual output "+a"?

Answer (score 2):

```
Send {+}a
```

or

```
SendRaw +a
```

should work also

This can be found at: [Autohotkey Send command documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Comment: I replaced your documentation link  with more uptodate version. Always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website). AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them.

Comment: You could also "shift" the = sign (on US keyboard) to get a plus like this Send, +=a